# How can I add a HyperLinkField to GridView databound to a file directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to Add a hyperlinkfield column to a GridView that pulls filenames from a file directory on the server.  I'm using the code below, but it's not exactly working.  It's showing the path and the filename, but it's not a clickable hyperlinkfield.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, can anyone help me out?

```
public void GetFilesAndFolders()
    {
        using (IREPEntities dbContext = new IREPEntities())
        {

            String vcharTempFileLocation = (from a in dbContext.tbl_ApplicationSetting
                                            where a.vcharKey == "vcharTempFileLocation"
                                            select a).Single().vcharValue;

            DataTable gridviewSource = DisplayFilesInGridView();
            DataRow gridviewRow;

            //Get All Folders Or Directories and add in table  
            DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(vcharTempFileLocation);
            DirectoryInfo[] subDirectories = directory.GetDirectories();

            foreach (DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirectories)
            {
                gridviewRow = gridviewSource.NewRow();
                gridviewRow["Claim"] = ddlClaimNumber.SelectedItem;
                gridviewRow["Name"] = dirInfo.Name;
                dynamic newlink = new HyperLinkField();

                newlink = vcharTempFileLocation + dirInfo.Name;

                gridviewRow["link"] = newlink;
                gridviewRow["Application"] = chkApplicationType.SelectedItem;

                gridviewSource.Rows.Add(gridviewRow);
            }




            //Get files in all directories  

            FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in files)
            {
                gridviewRow = gridviewSource.NewRow();
                gridviewRow["Claim"] = ddlClaimNumber.SelectedItem;
                gridviewRow["Name"] = fileInfo.Name;
                dynamic newlink = new HyperLinkField();

                newlink = vcharTempFileLocation + fileInfo.Name;

                gridviewRow["link"] = newlink;
                gridviewRow["Application"] = chkApplicationType.SelectedItem;                                   

                gridviewSource.Rows.Add(gridviewRow);
            }                        


            gvBatchDetails.DataSource = gridviewSource;
            gvBatchDetails.DataBind();

        }

    }
    private DataTable DisplayFilesInGridView()
    {
        DataTable dtgridviewSource = new DataTable();
        dtgridviewSource.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Claim", typeof(System.String)));
        dtgridviewSource.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(System.String)));
        dtgridviewSource.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Application", typeof(System.String)));
        dtgridviewSource.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("link", typeof(System.String)));

        return dtgridviewSource;
    }


}
```

Comment: Unless these files are located in the virtual directory, you're going to have a hard time making them available through the application using just hyperlinks.

Comment: How would putting it ina virtual directory help?  The files are all located in the same folder on the server, so I'm guessing that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building the GridView manually, create a datasource that you can bind to.

First create a custom class to hold the details:

```
public class FileOrFolderDetail
{
    public string Claim{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Link{get;set'}
    public string Application{get;set;}
}
```

Next, create a `List` of your new class:

```
var fileOrFolderDetails = new List<FileOrFolderDetail>();
```

At that point, go through your two loops like you're doing, but create new `FileOrFolderDetail` objects and add them to the `List`.

Finally, bind your `GridView` to `fileOrFolderDetails`, and set up your `HyperLinkField` in the ASPX to use `Link` as the `DataNavigateUrl`.

Let's start there and we can tweak as necessary.